# Migrating Google Firestore to AWS DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, amazon-dynamodb

I have been developing a web application in my free time and have been learning a lot. In this adventure, I have found a desire to migrate to AWS. The only problem: I have a lot of information already collected and stored in Google Firebase.

My question is: What are the best means of migrating information from Firestore to DynamoDB? Should I create an API to query information from my Firestore instance and write it to my DynamoDB instance, is there a migration utility, or can I download my Firestore Database and upload it to DynamoDB?

I apologize in advance if there is an easy solution which I may have missed.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you already checked this [guide](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/c2c0b179-6b4e-4133-8ea7-989fd2ba71a1/en-US/migrate/target-architecture/api-tier)?